# How to compile GUI who uses Simulink model?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, compilation, simulink

I have a GUI in where I introduce parameters for evalute in Simulink model, now I want to compile this application to .exe, GUI call a script who call model and returns some operations with data provide by simulation.
Is there some way to build that app?
I will be very grateful for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you, but works from MATLAB 2020a version
https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/349376-creating-a-standalone-exe-of-an-m-file-that-calls-a-simulink-model

https://de.mathworks.com/help/slcompiler/ug/deploy-a-simulation-with-simulink-compiler.html

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. It is accurate. The Simulink Compiler is required to build an application with a model built in.